# Java and SQL: ResultSetMetaData and ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans-8

I really need help. I am trying to retrieve a data from in my database using ResultSetMetaData and ResultSet. Also I am using a stored Procedure. The program is run find, however when I run it and be expecting 3 result from the row, instead it will give me 2. **For example if I ask a user to enter a position and there are 6 player in that position, it will give me 5 players instead of 6 player.**

Here is my code

```
            if (!rs.next()) {


                System.out.println("There is no match in the database " + position);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(String.format("  " + " %-19s %s", "Name",
                        "Rank") + "\t" + String.format("%-11s %s", "Position",
                                "School") + "\t" + String.format("%-6s %s",
                                        "Age", "War") + "\n-----------------"
                        + "-------------------------------------------------");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    int rank = 0, age = 0;
                    String name = null, pos = null, sch = null;
                    double war = 0;
                    for (int i = 1; i < colum - 1; i++) {

                        rank = rs.getInt(1);
                        name = rs.getString(2);
                        pos = rs.getString(3);
                        sch = rs.getString(4);
                        age = rs.getInt(5);
                        war = rs.getDouble(6);
                    }
```

[When I run my java code I get this result. It's not getting the first index in the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWHZ5.png)

[When I call my stored procedure in MYSQL Workbench, I get this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L40q1.png)

Answer (score 3):

You have read first index in

```
    if (!rs.next()) {
```

itself. This will move the cursor to the next row. You will have to remove this and it will give all the rows.

Comment: That's great! You may accept the answer then if you wish.